# Is there a general way to disable web site's link colour customisation for an entire domain?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, css

I do not mind whichever web browser it is (FireFox, Chrome, Edge). is there any easy way to prevent web sites from customising link colours?

The reason is that many Korean web sites override the colour of hyperlinks in a message board. Normally, visited links turn purple, but Korean web sites disable that behaviour, so all links (whether visited or not) look the same. This makes it really difficult to use the site when I open a link and then go back and open the next link, because I forget the last one I opened.

Comment: Some browsers - I'm not sure which ones - allow you to create a CSS style sheet which gets applied to all pages you browse to. By providing the CSS for links only, and making them `!important`, you can override the site's misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of extensions for this: [for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=visited), [for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/visited%20links%20color?_category=extensions), [for Stylish add-on](https://userstyles.org/styles/browse?search_terms=visited%20links%20color). Most of them work globally though, but some allow you to customize domains via settings. All of them do essentially one thing, add CSS like the one below to the pages. Just find an add-on with the most satisfying UI for you.

```
:visited {
    color: purle !important;
}
```